# Switch autocomplete on/off on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autocomplete

I want to turn on/off on autocomplete an input in Chrome, later idea is to inject custom suggestions for emails after a the next letter of an '@' char.

I get to turn autocomplete on/off but autocomplete values doesn't disappear until next key is pressed.

I have a demo here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/superunknown/35p4xvjt/)

```
const input = document.querySelector('[name=email]');

function handleChange(evt) {
  const target = evt.target;
  const value = evt.target.value;
  const idx = evt.target.value.indexOf('@');
  console.log(value.length, '-', idx);

  if (evt.target.value && idx !== -1 && value.length > (idx + 1) ) {
    target.autocomplete = 'off';
  } else {
    target.autocomplete = 'on';
  }
}

input.addEventListener('keydown', handleChange);
input.addEventListener('keyup', handleChange);
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRNYk.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To disable autocompletion in forms, you can set the autocomplete attribute to "off":

```
autocomplete="off"
```

You can do this either for an entire form, or for specific input elements in a form:

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to do it dynamicalle and have the autocomplete popup hide after it switches from on to off, on fiddle and on the screen there is an example that autocomplete is 'off' but popup will not hide until next key is pressed